# xml format needed in rails 3.0.1??? answer should be NO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, format

what the heck am I doing wrong.

I changed nothing, but now that it is 2011 this call doesn't work as it used to.

Using Active Resource, I can make the following call:

```
>> Member.find(:all, :params => {:code => "1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02"})
GET http://localhost:3000/members.xml?code=1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02
--> 500 Internal Server Error  (1601 371ms)
ActiveResource::ServerError: Failed with 500 Internal Server Error
```

As you can see, I get a 500 error.  So i go to my server to where i'm making the call.

The code is here in the controller:

```
def index
  @store = Store.first
  @members = @store.members.find_by_code(params[:code])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render @members.to_xml } # i also tried :xml => @members but that screws up too the same way.
  end
end
```

But below is the stack trace.  It's doing my head in why this just stopped working.

```
Started GET "/members.xml?code=1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-21 13:58:00 -0500
  Processing by MembersController#index as XML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02"}
  SQL (0.8ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Store Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `stores`.* FROM `stores` LIMIT 1
  Member Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE (`members`.store_id = 1) AND (`members`.`code` = '1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02') LIMIT 1
Completed   in 268ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template 

  4
  1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02
  2010-12-02T20:14:54Z
  3
  70.2
  10
  http://fnd.nu/7
  1
  2010-12-09T15:37:42Z

 with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:xml], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/nerb/current_project/fund/app/views", "/Users/nerb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/views", "/Users/nerb/current_project/fund", "/"):
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:14:in `index'

Rendered /Users/nerb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (31.6ms)
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.  I thought xml formats were expempt from render?  Jose said as much in this [lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1771-render-xml-and-render-nothing-with-layouts), but i can't find what he is talking about.

UPDATE:

Andy that worked as the Server seems to be sending a 200 so thanks, but now i get this error:

```
Member.find(:all, :params => {:code => "1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02"})
GET http://localhost:3000/members.xml?code=1stb48024957856464d436e79ad9d7bc0c2d46d5a02
--> 200 OK  (472 399ms)
NoMethodError: undefined method `collect!' for #
    from /Users/nerb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activeresource-2.3.5/lib/active_resource/base.rb:662:in `instantiate_collection'
    from /Users/nerb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activeresource-2.3.5/lib/active_resource/base.rb:639:in `find_every'
    from /Users/nerb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activeresource-2.3.5/lib/active_resource/base.rb:582:in `find'
    from (irb):1
```

Thoughts?  should it just be an array coming back, even if it's ONE record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render :xml => @members` is the way to go.

Make sure you reload/restart your server after making this change if in production.

Comment: I've done a million times man, but i will try again.  This one is going to take supernatural voodoo crud to make work.

Comment: At the least, it should generate a different (better?) error.

Comment: LOL, so true.  So I updated the question, thanks, any ideas on that one?

Comment: You should see the hack i had to do, so that both xml and html could be used with devise and the Member model.  Basically i created an obfuscated controller, that makes a Member#show call.  The format that responds is only xml there, and authenticated.  In my Member model, well that is just normal and used for the html gui. Get her working first, then make her pretty.